# Instantiating abstract class object in inheriting class

Tags: c#, inheritance

I need to find a way to instantiate an object from the abstract base class called Cell, inside the inheriting class called Spreadsheet. Everywhere I look people say it can't be done, but I am required to do it for a part of my homework and it specifically says that we can not make the parent class non abstract.

Here is the exact quote from the homework:

> Again, you need to come up with a design here that actually allows the
>   spreadsheet to create cells and there were hints before about how to
>   do this. You cannot make the publicly declared cell class
>   non-abstract.

The only "hints" i can think of is that the parent class is public abstract, the inheriting class is just a public class, and they are both in the same DLL.

Anyone have any ideas?

edit: (for more info)
The spreadsheet class is supposed to hold a 2d array of Cells. so in order to populate this 2d array, we need to make cell objects and put then in the corresponding indexes in the 2d spreadsheet array. The only problem is that we cant make any cells because the cell class is abstract. So, how can i make a cell and put it in the array?

Comment: I don't see anything in the homework about the question you are asking. Can you describe it differently or add more detail? Because it doesn't make sense as written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means you need to use `Cell` as a base class, and the inheriting class needs to have at least some of the implementation.

It seems like this particular homework assignment is a bit of what would be called a "[hospital pass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hospital_pass)" in football terms - `Spreadsheet` should not inherit from `Cell` as you mention.

In any case once you've written your derived class you can do this:

```
Cell myCell = new MyDerivedCell();
```

and voila, you have an instance of an abstract class (abstract classes cannot be instantiated directly).

The advantage of this is that you can put the bulk of the generic cell functionality into `Cell`, then specify some methods or properties that should be overridden for the more specialised derivations of the `Cell`.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm having some trouble with this. So I made a property in the Cell class abstract, and I declared another class called lclass that overrides the abstract property, but when I want to use the cell class constructor to make the cell it does not work. basically what i want is something like 'ICell cell = new ICell(i, j)' but the problem is the values the constructor is supposed to set are private in the abstract base class. Is there any way i can call the abstract base class constructor through the derived class to make the object?

Comment: Yes, you can chain constructors by using the [*base*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx) keyword as part of the ctor definition in the derived class. (Follow that link, it explains everything).